# How to convert wint_t to char

Tags: c

This is my code

```
    FILE * pFile;
FILE * fout;
wint_t wc;
int n = 0;
pFile = fopen("test.txt", "r");
fout = fopen("out.txt", "w");
if (pFile != NULL)
{
    do {
        wc = fgetwc(pFile);
        //fputwc ( wc , fout);
    } while (wc != WEOF);
    fclose(pFile);
    fclose(fout);
}
```

I want to read a sentence (in Persian) from a file then divide into two parts by using sub string function and finally store in an output file.
I want to know how I can convert wc variable to sequence of chars and divide into 2 parts?

Comment: `wint_t` is an integer type.  It may be some signed integer or some unsigned integer.  It may be 2x or 4x the size of a `char`  (or others) so storing in "sequence of chars and divide into 2 parts" is unclear.  If a `wint_t` is size 4, do you want each part to be a pair of `char`? Maybe providing the higher goal would help.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `for (i=0; i<sizeof wc; i++) printf("%c",  ((char*) &wc)[i]);` ?

Comment: for example, this is my sentence "سلام" and I want to divide it into "سل" and "ام".

Comment: If you replace `//fputwc ( wc , fout);` with `printf("%d ", (int) wc);`, what is the result?  `"216 179 217 132 216 167 217 133 "`?  Output likely affect by what editor used to make "test.txt" and how your compiler implements `wint_t`

Comment: this is my result : 239 187 191 216 179 217 132 216 167 217 133 65535. I'm using visual studio 2015

Comment: Your `fgetwc()` is reading one byte at a time from the file.  The first 3 are a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8)  the next 8 are UTF-8 encoding of `"سلام"` and the last is the `WEOF`.  To divide, code can convert the 8 byte sequence into 4 Unicode code-points.  To convert those  4 code-points may be as simple as divide by 2, but the nuances of language processing may say otherwise.  You may benefit with a new approach rather than using `wint_t`.  Good luck.